# Comparing Times in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, time

I have four different DateTime boxes. Two boxes just displays the Date and the other two just Displays the time

If the current time is between midnight and six am I want the Date in the date box to be the day before.

I have it all, I'm just missing the part that compares the two.

```
Dim currentTime As DateTime = Now
        'default date
        If deMaxDate.Value = Nothing Then
            deMaxDate.Value = Now
        End If
        If deMinDate.Value = Nothing Then
            If currentTime.Hour < TimeOfDay.Hour Then
            'THIS IF STATMENT IS WRONG - HOW CAN I CHECK IF ITS BETWEEN 12AM AND 6 HERE
                deMinDate.Value = (Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
            Else
                deMinDate.Value = Now
            End If
        End If
            'default time
            If teMaxTime.Value = Nothing Then
                teMaxTime.Value = Now
            End If
            If teMinTime.Value = Nothing Then
                teMinTime.Value = (Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(6))
            End If
```

My comment by the  third if statment is where I'm stuck at.
DateTime is a double datatype? Something like
if currentTime.Hour < TimeOfDay.Hour.Equals(6)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentTime.Hour < TimeOfDay.Hour.Equals(6)

ended up being the answer

Comment: You are over complicating it `.Hour` is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
If currentTime.Hour <= 6 Then
     deMinDate.Value = Now.AddDays(-1)
Else
     deMinDate.Value = Now
End If
```

or indeed...

```
If currentTime.Hour <= 6 Then
     deMinDate.Value = Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
Else
     deMinDate.Value = Now.Date
End If
```

if you don't want the time bit because `.Now` contains a time element as well as a date element.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule, if I understand this, is that you want to look at the current time. If the current time is between 12AM(0000) and 6AM(0600), then you want to use yesterday as the active date.

```
Dim current as DateTime = now()
Dim activeDate as DateTime = current
if current.Hour < 6 then
    activeDate = current.AddDays(-1)
end if
```

Although, if you're not really interested in the hours part of the date except for this business rule, you could always just do `date.AddHours(-6)`.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in a similar situation where I want to check the current time is prior to 4 AM.

```
If (DateTime.Now.Hour < 4) Then
   'do something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx. It might apply to your case