# How to compare/calculate time values in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

So I have this datetimepicker formatted to pick/show only time values. If I pick a time before a specific time, say, 6 PM, a label should say "Undertime", otherwise it should say "Overtime". I also want to find the timespan difference between the picked time and 6 PM.

I've tried these codes, but didn't work like I wanted:

```
If tp.Value > #6:00:00 PM# Then

Label1.Text = "Overtime: " & (tp.Value - #6:00:00 PM#).ToString

Else

Label1.Text = "Undertime: " & (#6:00:00 PM# - tp.Value).ToString

 End If
```

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863873/comparing-times-in-vb-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863873/comparing-times-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`. The problem is that your `Date` has a time part of 18 which is correct, but it's `date` part's year is 0 (since your `Date` literal doesn't contain a date-part it's initialized with the default date) which is always lower than the `DateTimePicker`'s `Date`.

So use `TimeSpan` and compare it with `DateTime.TimeOfDay` which is also a `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim time = TimeSpan.FromHours(18)
If tp.Value.TimeOfDay > time Then
    Label1.Text = "Overtime: " & (tp.Value.TimeOfDay - time).ToString
Else
    Label1.Text = "Undertime: " & (tp.Value.TimeOfDay - time).ToString
End If
```

A timespan has no  AM/PM-designation since it's always 24h based. If you want to format it properly with `hh:mm`-format you can use `TimeSpan.ToString`:

```
Dim diff As TimeSpan = tp.Value.TimeOfDay - time
Dim msg = String.Format("{0}: {1}",
   If(diff > TimeSpan.Zero, "Overtime", "Undertime"),
   diff.ToString("hh\:mm"))
Label1.Text = msg
```

This replaces all of your code above.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get it to ignore the seconds part, and just display the hours and minutes, as in the format "hh:mm tt". Thanks for any help.

Comment: A timespan has no  AM/PM-designator since it's always 24h based. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that second block of codes, but it got the job done for me. I'm currently googling the String.Format() part. Again, thanks Tim.